# Ubuntu installation unknown issue

Tags: usb-installation

I'm currently trying to install ubuntu onto my pc. Making a switch from windows 10. I created my bootable usb using rufus following the instructions on their website. But when I boot off that usb stick I get a purple screen with a small icon at the bottom then switches to a dos screen with a error message and doesnt load anything just shuts my screen off and doesnt do anything else.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIVsP.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with information on your hardware, and what ubuntu iso you have downloaded.

Comment: You haven't said which release of Ubuntu, however when you first see that *keyboard-in-rectangle* & *person-in-circle* prompt and you hit a key a menu will appear, allowing a "*Check disk for defects*" which would be my first step  (iie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck which will test your install media for defects, and CD refers to CD/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive or any other media used)

Comment: Quad core msi n1996 am2 socket 6gb ram I have have downloaded the correct amd64 of 19.1 ubuntu

Comment: When that display comes up I show my cursor on screen but it will not move and no key board inputs do anything  will eventually goto a nother screen

Comment: 19.1?  There was no release in 2019-January (Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* for server & desktop). Did you verify ISO after download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)? and then verify your write to install media? (link in prior comment), however I'd also verify if you actually downloaded Ubuntu, as there is no Ubuntu 19.1 release.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is up for download from ubuntu.com.. I have also tried 18.04.4 lts. Also tried mint instead and I could get a bit further I can run the os from the usb to try it not not install

Answer (score 0):

I would look at going to the *advanced welcome page* options and playing with boot parameters [as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions?action=show&redirect=BootParameters) if possible.

If you’re running a nvidia card you may need to disable the nouvea drivers

Comment: I am running nvidia card. I'm really sorry but any help with disabling that would be very much appreciated.. total noob to this